# call a function inside a plugin of the same object jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hi I want to implement into my plugin a function inside an object.
The goal is:
I have many input with a default value.
When I click on It if the value is "default value" cancel the text inside. And this it works.
The problem is now that:
When I submit the form I call a function that check parameter and I want that if the input type have the default value cancel the value. But now only the last element do that and not all object. I have create a function inside the main function of the plugin. How to check every object inside the plugin when submit and check if has the default value or not?

my plugin:

```
(function($){
     $.fn.extend({      
        contact: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);      
                var value_base = obj.val();

                obj.click(function(){
                    if(obj.val()== value_base){
                        obj.val("");
                    }
                });
                obj.blur(function() {
                    if (obj.val() == ''){
                        obj.val(value_base);
                    }
                });

                $.fn.afterSubmit = function(options) {
                    if(obj.val()== value_base){
                        obj.val("");
                    }
                };

            });
        }
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

the code inside my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contact').contact();
});
function autoriz(){
    $('.contact').afterSubmit();
    return false;
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="contatti.php" onSubmit="return autoriz();" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contatti">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="contact" value="Name" id="name"/>
   <input type="text" name="surname" class="contact" value="Surname" id="surname"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not loop through your element using JQuery submit event?

Comment: Because after i have to call in the same function another function of the plugin after another check because if the check return false i have to insert into the input the default value. In the submit event i have three function first the aftersubmit second a function of another plugin and  third the restore input if check is false

Comment: remove $.fn.afterSubmit from the Each scope. It is only happening once because he uses the last object in your each method. In the scope of your plugin, bind an event to the inputs class(an event like beforeSubmit or similar)

Comment: The function must be inside each because the var value_base is inside it. not? @RodrigoDias

Comment: No, you have to bind these input to an event outside the scope of each. When you bind these inputs by their class, in the moment event is triggered, inside the function the reserved keyword "this" will be the jquery object(the field itself) then you can access its properties.

Comment: if I take all function $.fn.afterSubmit and put after the each doesn't enter into this function. I have put an alert and doesn't show it @RodrigoDias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/YskZy/

In this example we bind the event submit passing the form id, so before the form is submitted, we can clear the default values

Comment: ok fine but the goal is after reset the field I call another function of another plugin (yav) if return false I have to put again the default value. For this I haven't use the function submit

Comment: You have not noticed one thing. When the function submit return false, it Does NOT submit the form, so you can call your other plugin and depend on the return value you can do whetever you want and stop or allow form from being submitted .

Comment: ok but after I want to call a function to put again the value base. And this is the function that I haven't done. I want a function inside my plugin that put again the default value

Comment: your last comment is like: "read the guide"... isnt't a good answer for my problem.

Comment: alright, finally got it. I set the value of input to empty string just for test, and call the function in your plugin that takes an object and reset its default value.Notice that now the default options prototype your plugin.  http://fiddle.jshell.net/tJce2/